# Issue with creating an SSL certificate

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, ssl-certificate, https

I am having the following issue:

There is a Terminal Server name TERM-SRV.example.com running Windows Server 2012 that hosts a site "https://example.com/RDWeb".

There was a certificate that recently expired that shows it was issued by example.com to example.com.

I am not sure how one could be able to issue a certificate from a url to another url as i am only able to issue a (self signed) certificate issuing from the TERM-SRV to let's say example.com.

Please note that on the domain there isn't any Certification Authority.

I am a bit(?) confused here, is there any part i am probably missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found out what is going on with this situation:

It seems that when you have the Remote Desktop Gateway installed as Server Role, using the role's panel you can manually assing a certificate to a desired recipient and from a desired issuer.

That means that if one wanted to issue a certificate to example.com with example.com as the issuer all he has to do is to just type in the name he wants on both fields.

I have never done this before so i was in pain for a while but it turned out that it was something easy to do.